# Are there any complicated BPEL samples or demos that can be found on the Internet?

Tags: web-services, workflow, sample, bpel

I want some complicated BPEL samples (more than just hello world), some real-world sample to analyze, about 40~50 BPEL activities (such as invoke, assign) would be OK.

I have searched for several days, but I just can't find. Are there any such samples that can be found on the Internet?

Answer (score 0):

I troubled the same problem,I want  some complicated  BPEL samples to analyze the data race or some currency errors.. But I have searched nearly a month,just find some samples in Oracle JDeveloper. It can be find in the ../sample directory.